# VS Remote Debugging

Tags: .net, remote-debugging

I'm very unfamiliar with traditional debugging, but we are having an issue on a production server and it would come in very handy right now, but I can't even get VS to connect to the remote machine and show any processes.

I've installed the remote debugging tools from MS.  The remote computer is one that I have  VPN connection to (I can browse to \172.25.250.66\c$ from windows explorer -- I am not sure, but I thought this meant that I was on the same network as the remote machine, but maybe I'm wrong).

Debug -> Attach Process, even if I choose Remote (no authentication) I can't see any other computers besides my own.

Comment: have you tried to write the IP address (and also don't forget the port of the remote debugger) in the text field?

Comment: are you sure that you have installed remote debugger for same version of VS which you have on client side?

Comment: @roqz Ok, I did not define a port.  I'll look into that.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic I just checked -- yes, I'm using VS2012, and I went to the page where I downloaded the remote debugger tools, and it is 2012 as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Remote (no authentication)` won't work for managed debugging.

You'll need to use `Default` transport. For that you will need the same users (and I believe also the same passwords) on both your computer where you are debugging and on the remote machine. On your computer, the Visual Studio process must run as that user, and of course on the remote machine the remote debugging process as well.

Comment: Dang it. That won't work.  I have to enter in a domain\username and password when I browse to that machine.  I probably can't replicate that.  Thanks for the information.